# jQuery arguments passed to event-handler are evaluated on binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, argument-passing, evaluation

I have the following code :

```
var profileToRemove = null;

//...

$("#buttonRemoveProfile").on("tap", {profile : profileToRemove}, removeProfile);

//...

function removeProfile(event){
   console.log(event.data);
   var profile = event.data.profil;
   if(profile==null || profile.name==null) {
      alert("Erreur lors de la suppression du profil");
   }
   else { /*remove profile*/ }
}
```

Before any tap on "#buttonRemoveProfile", "profileToRemove" is set to the desired value (not null!).
Yet, my function removeProfile receives "null" (event.data is {profile : null}) or whatever the initial value of profileToRemove was.

So how can I pass the current value of removeProfile to my handler?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your design so that the data contains a function that returns what you want:

```
$("#buttonRemoveProfile").on("tap", {profile : function() {
        return profileToRemove;
    }
}, removeProfile);

function removeProfile(event){
   console.log(event.data);
   var profile = event.data.profile(); // Call the profile function
   if(profile==null || profile.name==null) {
      alert("Erreur lors de la suppression du profil");
   }
   else { /*remove profile*/ }
}
```

If you want to get fancy, you could allow the profile to be either a function or data, and use:

```
var profile = event.data.profile;
if (typeof profile == "function") {
    profile = profile();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The data parameter in `on()` takes an object, and the value of that object is locked in at the time of binding, changing the `profileToRemove` variable later does not in any way update `event.data.profile` (which you typed incorrectly).

[**PROOF**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/YYS5A/)

As you already have a variable in a higher scope, it seems easier to use that directly

```
var profileToRemove = null;

$("#buttonRemoveProfile").on("tap", removeProfile);

//...

function removeProfile(){
   if( profileToRemove === null || profileToRemove.name === null) {
      alert("Erreur lors de la suppression du profil");
   } else { 
      /*remove profile*/ 
   }
}
```